# What is the formula to calculate age days?

Tags: sql

Currently I have a problem, I can't get how old in days something is. I'm trying to get it to appear like:

2 MONTHS AND 14 DAYS

---

```
DECLARE n_yr INT(11);

    DECLARE n_mon INT(4);

    DECLARE n_day INT(4);   

  

    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( YEAR, prev_dte, cur_dte ) INTO n_yr;

    SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF( MONTH, prev_dte, cur_dte ) % 12 INTO n_mon;

    SELECT FLOOR( TIMESTAMPDIFF( DAY, prev_dte, cur_dte ) %30.5375 ) INTO n_day;

  

    IF n_yr THEN

        RETURN CONCAT(n_yr, IF(n_yr > 1, ' years', ' year'));

    ELSEIF n_mon THEN

        RETURN CONCAT(n_mon, IF(n_mon > 1, ' months ', ' month '), n_day, IF(n_day > 1, ' days', ' day'));

    ELSE

        RETURN CONCAT(n_day, IF(n_day > 1, ' days', ' day'));

    END IF;
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Please only tag a single RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

See this sample.

1. I calculate the month from start to enddate
2. I calculate the days startdate + month to enddate

```
    Start date = 1959-02-01
    End.  date.  2003-05-04
```

```
    SELECT CONCAT(
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'1959-02-01','2003-05-04'),
      ' MONTH AND ',
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,'1959-02-01' + INTERVAL 
      TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'1959-02-01','2003-05-04') MONTH,'2003-05-04')
      ,' DAYS');
```

OUTPUT

```
531 MONTH AND 3 DAYS
```